# The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, datetime

I have a controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Auction auction)
{
    var db = new EbuyDataContext();
    db.Auctions.Add(auction);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return View(auction);
}
```

A model:

```
public class Auction
{
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal StartPrice { get; set; }
        public decimal CurrentPrice { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }}
}
```

And a view:

```
@model Ebuy.Website.Models.Auction
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>
        //All the information fields...
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EndTime)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndTime)
    </p>
}
```

When I try to run it I receive the error:

> The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

The model-controller-view is from a book copied one-to-one.

What is the format that I need to enter to the `EndTime` field so I won't have this error?

Comment: Have you checked the values that is being saved for StartTime and EndTime?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The error is because you haven't actually set those values correctly, make sure you set them depending on your applications locale. (e.g. dd/mm/yyyy for `en-GB`, mm/dd/yyyy for `en-US`).

It also looks like your database has been set up to use a `datetime2` column and **not** a `datetime` column.

You can either:

A) Modify the database to change the type from `datetime2` to `datetime`

B) Change the types in your Model to be `datetime2`, by doing:

```
[Column(TypeName = "DateTime2")]
public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

[Column(TypeName = "DateTime2")]
public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
```

Comment: how can i modify the db settings?

Comment: @AlexandraOrlov If your database is code first, then applying those attributes and regenerating the database should be fine.

Comment: I changed the type in my model and used the dd/mm/yyyy version. I still dont understand how i am supposed to modify db settings but thanks for the answer

Comment: By the way, i guess it sounds VERY stupid, but where do i have the access to the DB? where i can see the table generated by the EbuyDataContext?

Comment: @AlexandraOrlov Ah that's fine then, there's no need to change the DB then. You should have either SQL Server Express or normal installed? Open up SQL Server Management Studio and login to `localhost`, you should see your DB.

Comment: got you, thanks! i thought it supposed to use the SQL that visual studio has

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem when I tried to save an unassigened DateTime member to the DB, while using EntityFramework.
I read the answers here, and I learned that it can be solved by declaring the member as nullable. I tried it, and it worked!
So here is a code snap, for those who need it:

```
public Nullable<DateTime> MyDateTime { get; set; }
```

or

```
public DateTime? MyDateTime { get; set; }
```

Later I could use it like bellow:

```
if(MyDateTime.HasValue)
{
    DoBlaBla(MyDateTime.Value);
}
```

or just assign a value to it like nothing had happen...

```
MyDateTime = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: This did the trick for me, as I added a Birthdate field to my IdentityUser model

Answer (score 3):

Does your columns with datetime2 datatype accepts null values. If not then you might get this error when you are not assigning a value to these columns.

By default the CodeFirst will make non nullable columns if your model does not use nullable properties. Try converting these properties to nullable datetime.

Comment: as you can see in the model, i dont have any restrictions. and what is datatime2 column?

Comment: It is column with datetime2 datatype at database level. Sorry for the typing mistake. Does your database level column accept null values?

Comment: Hmm... I am not sure. As i learn it right now from the book, i tried the "code first" version, created a model: public class EbuyDataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Auction> Auctions { get; set; }...

Comment: @AlexandraOrlov: It should solve the problem if you make model properties StartTime and EndTime as nullable DateTime

Answer (score 0):

I also struck this problem.

***The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value*** is a very un-useful error that one receives.

To resolve the problem I had to do the following (Using the above example):

One can find the Package Manager Console from -> Tools -> Library Package Manager -> Package Manager Console

I enabled Database Migrations in Package Manager Console -> Enable-Migrations

Then added the below code in the Controller Class:

```
public class Auction
{
public long Id { get; set; }
public string Title { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public decimal StartPrice { get; set; }
public decimal CurrentPrice { get; set; }

// My Edit to the code Start -->
public Nullable<DateTime> StartTime { get; set; }
public Nullable<DateTime> EndTime { get; set; }}
// My Edit to the code Finish <--
}
```

Then in the Models Class:

```
[HttpPost]

// My Edit to the code Start -->
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode=true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]]
// My Edit to the code Finish <--

public ActionResult Create(Auction auction)
{

// My Edit to the code Start -->
if(ModelState.IsValid)
{
// Only Apply the DateTime if the Action is Valid...
auction.StartTime = DateTime.Now;
}
// My Edit to the code Finish <--

var db = new EbuyDataContext();
db.Auctions.Add(auction);
db.SaveChanges();
return View(auction);
}
```

Then Add to the Database the changes in the Package Manager Console -> Add-Migration (Your Change goes here)

Then run a Database Update in the Package Manager Console -> Update-Database

Its important to see that the Data that the Database see's is correct in the above implementation:

```
E.G: 17/06/2013 12:00:00 AM
```

This error is an amazingly stupid error but it seems to have caught a lot of people out including my self. Now I know why this error occurs it seems that it is easy to fix and get around but why such a common issue would not be fixed in the last release of MVC is beyond my comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

I got the similar error when i was trying to add change_date to my contact entity in the service layer. The issue was resolved by adding the parameter from controller. Please try to add the parameter from Controller.

Answer (score 0):

I had a default getdate() value on DateCreated in the DB.  I wasn't setting the value in EF because I didn't think I needed to.  Once I passed in the value through EF on the insert then the error went away.  Why is that error there in the first place?  I never figured that out.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend making the DateTime property nullable and also using attribute validation to make sure the value is within the acceptable range.

I created a custom attribute inherited from RangeAttribute to validate the date value.

```
public class DbDateRangeAttribute
    : RangeAttribute
{
    public DbDateRangeAttribute()
        : base(typeof(DateTime), SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value.ToShortDateString(), SqlDateTime.MaxValue.Value.ToShortDateString())
    { }
}
```

And then you use the attribute like that

```
[DbDateRange]
public DateTime? StartTime { get; set; }
```

Like that, if the user enters a value outside the range of SqlDateTime (probably because of a client-side date picker issue), he will get a meaningful error message like the following:

> The field StartTime must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and
>   12/31/9999 12:00:00 AM.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this with my system fields (created_on, modified_on) even though my model was defined properly.

The cause of my issue was using the disabled attribute vs readonly.  Forms will not submit disabled input values to the controller which resulted in the null value which, in turn, resulted in the min date/time value.

Wrong:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreatedOn, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-lg-3" })
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreatedOn, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", disabled="disabled" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreatedOn, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Right:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreatedOn, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-lg-3" })
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreatedOn, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly="readonly" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreatedOn, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This post - [Solution to: “The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value” with Entity Framework when calling SaveChanges - proposes to use the attribute](http://blog.jongallant.com/2013/07/datetime2-datetime-out-of-range-ef.html). It solved the issue for me.

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> Created { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, this error caused me hours of frustration, as one day my code stopped working on my localhost, but the app on the UAT server was fine. As I use a corporate network, tracked it down to windows update that changed my date regional settings from yyyy/mm/dd  to dd/mm/yyyy (I am writing to SQL).

Again, Check for any changes to your Regional Settings

**Search**->**Set Regional Format**->**Additional date,time & regional settings**, update to correct format