# Where is the db/table generated by Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am learning MVC 4 from O'Reilly book (Programming ASP.NET MVC4) and have followed its steps so now have a class as:

```
public class Auction
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal StartPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal CurrentPrice { get; set; }
    //[Column(TypeName = "DateTime2")]
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    //[Column(TypeName = "DateTime2")]
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
}
```

and as you know better I have to go with EF (eh) and when I run the code I get and error as

> The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value. The statement has been terminated.

Yes, I know it is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16298616/mvc4-the-conversion-of-a-datetime2-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type-error) on SOF and discussed but from the answers on SOF I found that i can do a conversion in the table. As you see I have commented out the attributes in the class since using them leads me to a new error as:

> The model backing the 'eBayDataContext' context has changed since the
>   database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update
>   the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

Beside this situation: I cannot see any DB or table made in SQL Server. How can I locate the table/DB generated by EF? I have checked but nothing I do see here!

This is my connectionString

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-eBay-20140404154307;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-eBay-20140404154307.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2010:

1. View --> Server Explorer
2. Click Connect to Database icon.
3. Leave defaults and enter (LocalDb)\v11.0 for the Server name field.
4. In the Connect to a database section at the bottom, click the down arrow for the dropdownlist (Select or enter a database name:)  It will take a few seconds, but then you should see your database listed there (aspnet-eBay-20140404154307)
5. Select your database and click OK.

You'll now have a new connection to your database in the Server Explorer window. You can expand this connection and navigate to your Tables.

Comment: You must wrote ur server name in the list, not search for that.

Comment: Thanks but can you be more specific?

Comment: @Craig   Thanks I followed that but there is no such a name in drop-down list. any idea?                                                              the reason I think the Db/Table are created is because when I change my class it throws: **The model backing the 'eBayDataContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269). **

Comment: OK finally after several minutes it showed up!!! i am new to EF but by far it acts strange and I'm not crazy about it