# saving date time exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-controller, asp.net-mvc-views

I have a class callnote with contain entity

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime CallBAckDate { get; set; }
```

and my controller is like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateNote(CallNote callnote)
{
        YelloAdminDbContext db = new YelloAdminDbContext();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Note.Add(callnote);
            //var temp = db.Note.Find(FeedBack);
            //db.SaveFeedBack.Add(new SaveFeedBack { LoginId = id, feedback = temp });
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("CallHistory");
            //return JavaScript("alert('Success');");
        }
        return View("CallHistory", callnote);
}
```

and in view:

```
<div class ="editor-label">
        @Html.EditorFor(item => item.CallBAckDate)
        @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(item => item.CallBAckDate)*@

</div>
```

I am getting the exception:

> The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value. The statement has been terminated.

How I can resolve this exception?

Comment: if you are not passing date it will throw error in that case make datetime property nullable

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC4 - The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16298616/mvc4-the-conversion-of-a-datetime2-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type-error)

Comment: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/229/Conversion-of-a-datetime2-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type-resulted-in-an-out-of-range-value